# I keep getting java version 1.4.2 instead of any of the later versions

Tags: linux

I am using Linux

I downloaded the latest linux version from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-6u26-download-400750.html)

uploaded the .bin file to `/home/asimon/java`

executed the following commands

```
chmod 755 jdk-6u22-linux-i586.bin
./jdk-6u22-linux-i586.bin
```

and `jdk1.6.0_22` was created, but whenever i try to execute `java -version` from `/home/asimon/java/jdk1.6.0_22/bin` i get the below output, i.e., not `1.6.0` but `1.4.2`. What is creating the problem. I am also giving a screenshot of my `set`

**Screenshot 1**

[image]

**my** `set` **output screenshot**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type `which java` to find out which directory `java` is being picked up from. You probably need to correct your PATH. At the moment, you have `/home/asimon/java/bin` on your PATH, which must be an old version of java. You should update it to `/home/asimon/java/jdk1.6.0_22/bin`. The PATH variable would be present in `$HOME/.profile`.

Also, note that if you execute `./java -version` it will use the java executable present in the current working directory, instead of searching the PATH for it.

Answer (score 1):

You get whatever Java appears first in the list of directories in your PATH environment variable. The preinstalled Java is almost certainly in `/usr/bin`, so if you want to default to the self-installed one in `~/java/jdk1.6.0/bin`, you *must* change your PATH so that thiat directory comes before `/usr/bin`. The installation instructions should have told you how to do that.